# linkButton: passing variables

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to pass variables through linkButton in Yii, but nothing is reaching my controller.

View:

```
<?php echo CHtml::linkButton('Approve', array(
         'submit'=>array('comment/approve','id'=>$data->id),
         'params'=>array('CommentId' => $data->CommentId),
)); ?>
```

Controller dump:  Result is NULL

```
var_dump($_GET['CommentId']);
die();
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables passed using the `params` option end up in the `$_POST` array. You should see CommentId in:

```
var_dump($_POST['CommentId']);
```